# Threading with IProgressDialog in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, invoke

I want to add a native windows **ProgressDialog** to my c# application.
For better control i defined an *OnUserCancled* Event.
After **ShowDialog()** calls from main form,*ProgressDialog* class starts a thread that checks if native *ProgressDialog* is canceled or not.But the problem is the *IProgressDialog* belongs to main thread and it cannot be accessed from checker thread.The error is serious:

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'WindowsDialogs.Invokes.Interfaces.IProgressDialogC' to interface type 'WindowsDialogs.Invokes.Interfaces.IProgressDialog'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{EBBC7C04-315E-11D2-B62F-006097DF5BD4}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

I want to know is there any way to Invoke my commands to main class(like **Invoke()** method that is in .net Form ).

***Note: Timer class has the same problem...***

Comment: casting is not a problem in main thread but it may be a problem in socond thread...

Answer (score 0):

You should do all calls to the progress dialog in that UI thead.
In WPF I do:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate()
{
    _progressDialog.SetProgress(percentComplete, 100);
});
```

For WinForms, I guess that would be Control.Invoke:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @karlas this is a problem with cross thread calls.

Here is my solution using an internal timer to periodically monitor the cancel button state :

```
private void _timerCallback(object state)
{
    _parentForm.Invoke((Action) delegate {
        try
        {
            if (HasUserCancelled)
            {
                Cancelled?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Swallow
        }
    });
}
```

Where the `_parentForm` field is set in the `Show()` method like this:

```
public void Show(IWin32Window parent){
    if (_parentForm == null)
        _parentForm = Form.ActiveForm;
    ...
}
```